# How to Count and return the Values

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am facing a problem in the following script. I am not much into scripting at all and this is not my script also but here am getting the result which is grouping the values( For Example if i have a value A in three cells it should return the value as 3 instead it is returning AAA. Can someone help me out to count the values and return it

Thanks in Advance,

Here is the script :

```
function sumBackgroundColors(rangeString, color) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
var sumRange = s.getRange(rangeString);
//var sum = 0;
var openCount = 0;
var sumRangeBackground = sumRange.getBackgroundColors();
var sumRangeValues = sumRange.getValues();

for(var row = 0; row < sumRangeBackground.length; row++ ) {
for(var col = 0; col < sumRangeBackground[0].length; col++ ) {
if( sumRangeValues[row][col]=="LG M"&& sumRangeBackground[row][col] == color ) {
openCount = openCount + sumRangeValues[row][col];
//if(sumRangeBackground[row][col] == color && sumRangeValues[row][col] == 1 ) {
// sum = sum + parseFloat(sumRangeValues[row][col]);

} 
}
}
return openCount;
//return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which will take the value to be searched as argument. Rest of the things have been explained in comment lines.

```
function searchCount(value){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //Get the whole data from activesheet in a 2D array
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  //Initialize counter
  var count = 0;

  //Iterate through the array
  for(var i in data){
    for(var j in data[i]){
      // if a match found, increament the counter
      if(value.toString == data[i][j]){
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  // return the count value
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Waqar `value.toString` is probably wrong (missing parenthesis). Anyway, there's no need to parse the value, since the `==` operator already does that. And, what if the value is actually a number, date or boolean? Parsing does not make much sense to me :)

Answer (score 0):

your problem could be due to `openCount = openCount + sumRangeValues[row][col];`

According to your example **sumRangeValues[row][col]** isn't an int. *int + not an int = ???* if you want to keep a count of things you probably want **openCount++** to replace that line instead, which is just a shortcut to `openCount = openCount + 1;`

Even if **sumRangeValues[row][col]** *was* an int, that line still wouldn't be what you're looking for. If you're searching for all the 3s in your spreadsheet your code would find your first 3, and then that line would execute `0 = 0 + 3` congrats, you just found 3 threes. You would continue to add three every time you found a three.

Waqar's code is essentially your code (amazingly simplified, but it iterates the same way) except he doesn't check color and he uses ++ instead of that line.